# Bi-directional Map in Apex or best alternative approach

Tags: apex, performance

I am using Apex Map structures for fast one-way mapping of data. This works very well, but I ideally want to map backwards using the **same** map declaration.

The obvious way is to iterate the map, but it annoys me a bit that this won't work as fast/nice. I believe some other languages have data types specially for this kind of requirements, but I don't think there is one in Apex. Is there a better alternative than my current approach ?

```
  private static Map<string,string>  DUMMY_MAP = new map<string,string> {
                            '0' => 'OZKE-ZDSK',
                            '1' => 'AZERTSDSRTT',
                            '2' => '199951288',
                            '3' => '99567-555',
                            '4' => 'ZDDSD358*PE',
                            '5' => 'ZZPL?EKKE'
}; 

//main direction
string input = '0';
string output = DUMMY_MAP.get(input);

//reversed direction
for(string key:DUMMY_MAP.keySet()){
    if(output == DUMMY_MAP.get(key)){
         system.debug('the key for value '+output+' is ' + key +' !');
     }
 }
```

Comment: How are you constructing the original map, if through a loop you can construct the reverse lookup in the same loop potentially?

Comment: Hard coded declaration, there's no where to get it from unless we'd put it somewhere. We're doing this for a number of data types we receive from a webservice before we show the data on a VF page.

Comment: In that case I'd just hardcode the reverse declaration too, unless they're likely to change and then you ll have to end up updating two constants. Another idea might be to use custom settings and store them both ways so you're saved the resulting heap size of two maps

Comment: Thinking of the underlying Apex implementation...Java [doesn't have a bi-directional map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/collections/reference.html), but there are third party Java implementations that do, such as [Google's BiMap](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you expect a lot of this reverse-searching to happen you'll have to plan ahead - build reversed map in the beginning and then run your searches however you want.

A bit crazier idea is to serialize the hell out of it and do some JSON parsing ;)

Comment: Right - assuming all the keys AND values are unique, you could just do two maps, right?

Comment: @joshbirk of course :) Really depends how many reversed searches there will be... But come to think of it in terms of script statements - to be sure to waste 1 more statement on `put()` to second map while initializing (N total) sounds like better option than M reversed searches in a loop, each taking on average N / 2 + loop's iteration overhead ;)

Comment: @eyescream, are you saying there's a away do reverse it faster using JSON parsing? I've heard about this before, apparently Paul Battisson was using same technique in his machine learning implementations. I've never actually seen the code.